# Magento 2.2.8 > 2.3.5 upgrade hangs on "Something's changed, looking at all rules again"

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I'm trying to upgrade a Magento shop from 2.2.8 to 2.3.5 through composer. First, i've copied the shop from the live server to a local docker environment. Then I applied the upgrade on the local environment. The upgrade succeeded. However, when I tried to run the upgrade (composer update command) on the live server, composer seems to be stuck on "Something's changed, looking at all rules again".

I've checked composer versions and php versions but they are the same on local and live environment.

Anybody an idea what causes this issue?